# What was the logic behind state censuses?

Tags: united-states, census

Conducting genealogy research, I always liked when my targets were in times and places where they have state censuses to back up the federal census. Frequently, the state census is conducted in years ending in 5, i.e. 1885, 1895,1905, etc. This is nice because it gives you an update on your research target every 5 years, alternating between the state and federal censuses. Now, I am not sure when or why, but state censuses began to fall out of favor. For example,[Minnesota's last state census was 1905](https://libguides.mnhs.org/census/state#:%7E:text=After%20statehood%20was%20granted%20in,of%20the%20Minnesota%20State%20Census.) and [Massachusetts conducted a state census all the way up until 1975](https://www.sec.state.ma.us/arc/arcgen/genidx.htm#:%7E:text=Massachusetts%20State%20Census,the%20only%20two%20surviving%20schedules.), though interestingly, only two years of data survive, 1855/1865, I imagine fire is why, can anyone confirm that (irrelevant to the question).

I found [a really helpful Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_censuses_in_the_United_States) that lists when all state censuses were conducted. A scant few have regular repeating censuses for several years. Such as Massachusetts. MA had a few irregular censuses in the 18th-century, but from 1855 to 1985, every 10 years, MA conducted a census. Kansas is another example of regularity conducting censuses every 10 years starting in 1855 and running until 1925. However, these examples are the exception. There are several states that have a bunch of regular years, but then are surrounded by irregular years without patterns. Then, most of the states have basically zero discernable pattern to their censuses. And, lastly, a few such as OH, PA, WV, and others, have never conducted a census. The last U.S. state census appears to be Massachusetts' in 1985.

All of my Google searches asking why STATE censuses were conducted, only brings up answers as to why the federal census is conducted, and that is basically a) community planning (i.e. where a hospital or fire department is needed) b) to determine how federal funds are distributed, and c) to determine legislative districts and the number of seats a state holds in the House of Representatives. What I cannot figure out is the logic behind **state** censuses. There is a lot of time, effort, and money that goes into conducting a census, yet at some periods of time, in certain states, they were conducted quite frequently. Take Washington for example, conducting a census in 1856, 1857, 1858, and 1860. Or when Oregon was a territory, conducting censuses in 1842, '43, '45, '49, '50. '53, '54, '55, '56, '57, '58, and then the year after becoming a state 1859. Whatever the appeal of state censuses, it seems to have faded after 1931, as the only states still conducting them after this year were Florida, Massachusetts, Rhode Island, and South Dakota.

So, the question is why did we ever conduct state censuses in the first place, and why did we stop? I mean, **if** all the state censuses fell at the halfway marks between the federal censuses, it would make perfect sense. They are simply supplementing the federal census at regular intervals. This is far from the case however. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the practice of having State censuses end shortly after the widespread adoption of Hollerith cards by the federal census? What data are the states collecting that might not be collected federally (which possibly varies by state)? And is that slowly added to the federal census, making state censuses redundant.

Comment: I recommend you remove or seriously modify your last paragraph. Otherwise it might be closed because of biased opinions.

Comment: Certainly the example of Oregon points to a territory being very interested in showing how large the population is and how fast it is growing to convince Congress to make it a state. Washington may well fall into that bin as well. So, likely there are a variety of reasons to do them, and of course a variety of reasons to finally stop doing them (bureaucratic inertia is a powerful thing).

Comment: Seems likely they liked having the data for roughly the same reasons you do, but on a macro level. Another good question would be why it fell out of fashion. My SWAG for that would be that its a very labor-intensive task, and labor costs in the US went up rather a lot in the 20th century, making the process relatively less attractive to states. Also, modern surveying and polling techniques likely made it a bit redundant. These days we largely know what the Census is going to find before the numbers are released.

Comment: Also, the introduction of statewide voter registration systems, driver's licenses, handgun licenses, etc. has provided states with a wealth of information about where their residents live, making the need for a separate state census redundant.